# NSArrayM * returns "0 objects"

Tags: nsarray, empty-list, skproduct

I have a recurring error in my code.
When the app is built it works perfectly until I click on an in-app purchase then it crashes.

Here is the error log:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds for
>   empty array'
>
> *** First throw call stack:  (0x30fd4f4b 0x3b6a66af 0x30f0b533 0xe03d9 0x11ce01 0x1217d3   0xf696b 0x3379b507 0x319af38b 0x30fa00df
>   0x30f9fcf7 0x30f9e093   0x30f08c27 0x30f08a0b 0x35bdc283 0x337ac049
>   0xdee93 0xdede8) libc++abi.dylib:  terminating with uncaught exception
>   of type NSException (lldb)

And the related code:

```
//
//  main.m
//  Syntax
//
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); //This line in green with SIGABRT 1
    }
}
```

When I use an exception breakpoint, I got the following result:

```
- (void) purchase:(NSString*)purchase_id {
    if (![SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
        UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:@"inApp purchase Disabled"
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];

        return;
    }
    int ID = 0;

    if ([purchase_id isEqual: IAP_500_BYTES_PACK]){
            ID = 4;
    }
    else if ([purchase_id isEqual: IAP_1000_BYTES_PACK])
    {
            ID = 0;
    }
    else if ([purchase_id isEqual: IAP_3000_BYTES_PACK]){
            ID = 2;
    }
    else if ([purchase_id isEqual: IAP_7500_BYTES_PACK]){
            ID = 5;
    }

    else if ([purchase_id isEqual:  IAP_20000_BYTES_PACK]){
            ID = 1;
    }

    else if ([purchase_id isEqual:  IAP_50000_BYTES_PACK]){
            ID = 3;
    }

    else if ([purchase_id isEqual:  IAP_ADD_BACKGROUNDS]){
        ID = 6;
    }

    else if ([purchase_id isEqual:  IAP_FULL_VERSION]){
        ID = 7;
    }

SKProduct *productSK = [self.productRes objectAtIndex:ID]; // HERE is thread 1, breakpoint 1.1

if(productSK == nil){

        UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                message:@"Cannot connect to iTunes Connect"
                                                delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
    return;
}
```

In the local variables area it indicates:

> productSK __NSArrayM *    @"0 objects"    0x14d40300

My problem is I can't find why "productSK" is empty. It is correctly set , I think:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *productRes;
@synthesize productRes;
```

Can you help me, please?

Comment: where you fill values in productRes ?

Comment: 1) `productSK __NSArrayM * @"0 objects" 0x14d40300` you better watch self.productRes 2) do you use ARC ?

Comment: @sage444      
Here is "self.productRes":  
self.productRes = [NSMutableArray new];  
    for (SKProduct *product in response.products) {
        [self.productRes addObject:product];  
        NSLog(@"%@",product.productIdentifier);   
No, I don't use ARC

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're running into is indicated by `NSRangeException`. You're trying to get the 5th element from your array, but the array has no elements. In other words, at the time of the crash the contents are `@[ ]`.

You should have some code somewhere (possibly in your `init` method) that sets `self.productRes = ...`, where you're filling it with `SKProduct *`s for your in-app purchases.

Also, when your app crashes and the debugger places you in `main`, the crash is almost never actually there. This happens when an exception is thrown but not caught (so it reaches all the way to your program's entry point). When this happens you should set an [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) to see where the exception was thrown.

Comment: Hi wjl!
I only have "self.productRes" in three places: first one is the one you can read: **bold**'SKProduct *productSK = [self.productRes objectAtIndex:ID];'

by the way, I sent an exception breakpoint, you can read it.
Other two places are below:
**bold**' - (void)sendResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {self.productRes = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (SKProduct *product in response.products) {
        [self.productRes addObject:product];
        NSLog(@"%@",product.productIdentifier);
    }'

Comment: It looks like the `sendResponse` method would set the array properly. Does that method get called?

Comment: No,  sendResponse  is not called.

Comment: That explains why the array is empty.

Comment: I think my main problem is `productRes` is empty.
Breakdown point says it is waiting for an "id" type but receives an "int": "incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type 'id'."
Any way to solve it? Thanks!